# Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/guards' when setting up a microservice with NestJS

Tags: nestjs, microservices

I'm trying to set up a microservice using NestJS, and I've added the following dependencies in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
}
```

After running npm install, I tried to start the project using npm run start:dev, but I encountered the following error:

Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/guards'

[image]

Note: I installed all packages using [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/)

Comment: Would you consider yarn?

Comment: Also you have the latest version of @nestjs/microservices but not the others (@nestjs/common, @nestjs/core, etc), is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Nick_O I just installed `@nestjs/microservices`. Everything else came with nest-cli project generation.

Comment: @Nick_O With `yarn` everything works perfectly but not with pnpm

Comment: It must be a version & dependency issue where pnpm cannot resolve this automatically, Jay McDoniel appears to have a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure `@nestjs/common`, `@nestjs/core`, `@nestjs/microservice`, and `@nestjs/platform-express` are **all** on the **exact** same version. Easiest way to do this is just `rm -rf node_modules` and `rm pnpm-lock.yaml` to ensure when you run `pnpm i` they all come in as the same version. Otherwise, set them all the same in the `package.json` and `pnpm i` again to reinstall. You could also try `pnpm upgrade --interactive --latest` if you want a CLI to help with choosing.

When you run `pnpm nest info` it should have the aforementioned packages having the same versions